# Kafka Streams how to get TimeStamp from kafka message in scala

Tags: node.js, scala, apache-kafka, stream, timestamp

I am running a simple Kafka streams application that takes information logged using Node JS to a Kafka topic.

```
E.g. 
  Producer = kafka.Producer
  KeyedMessage = kafka.KeyedMessage
  client = new kafka.KafkaClient()
  producer = new Producer(client)
  km = new KeyedMessage('key', 'message')
  kafka_message = JSON.stringify({ id: req.session.data.toString(), url: article.info })
  payloads = [
    { topic: 'eventTopic', messages: kafka_message,timestamp:timestampNow}
  ];
  producer.send(payloads, function (err, data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

It's also important to note that a timestamp is just a number indicating the number of seconds since June 1970.

I am consuming this data using a Kafka Stream in scala.

For e.g.

```
val builder = new StreamsBuilder

val stream = builder
    .stream[String, String]("TopicTest")
    .foreach((k:String, v:String) => {
     println(k)
     println(v) 
}
```

However, I am unsure how to extract the timestamp (that I sent from nodeJS) to this stream.

For e.g. if I try to do something like this

```
val stream = builder
    .stream[String, String,Long]("TopicTest")
    .foreach((k:String, v:String,timeStamp:Long) => {
     println(k)
     println(v) 
     println(timeStamp)
}
```

This gives an error "Cannot resolve symbol stream". I was wondering how I can solve this.
Just for extra reference here's my topology and configs for my stream.
val topology = builder.build

```
  import java.util.Properties
  val props = new Properties()
  import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig

  val appId = this.getClass.getSimpleName.replace("$", "")
  props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, appId)
  props.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, appId)
  props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, ":9092")
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest")


  // Step 4. Create Kafka Streams Client
  import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams
  val ks = new KafkaStreams(topology, props)


  ks.start
```

Answer (score 0):

There does exist a TimeStampExtractor (https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-kafka-streams/content/kafka-streams-TimestampExtractor.html).
However, it is possible to send the timestamp to as any regular kafka message. The first thing I changed was my NodeJS code to this.

```
kafka_message = JSON.stringify({ id: req.session.information.toString(), url: article.info,timestamp:timestampNow.toString() })
  payloads = [
    { topic: 'eventTopic', messages: kafka_message}
  ];
 
  producer.send(payloads, function (err, data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

There is a timestamp field now in the JSON message I send.

Finally, we can parse through the JSON message using argonaut.

```
 val streamEvents = builder
    .stream[String, String]("testTopic")
    .foreach((k:String, json:String) => {
      println(k)
      println(json)
      println(Parse.parse(json))
      val url:String = Parse.parseWith(json, _.field("url").flatMap(_.string).getOrElse("Error!"), msg => msg)
      val id:String = Parse.parseWith(json, _.field("id").flatMap(_.string).getOrElse("Error!"), msg => msg)
      val timestamp:String = Parse.parseWith(json, _.field("timestamp").flatMap(_.string).getOrElse("Error!"), msg => msg)
      val timeStampInt:Long = timestamp.toLong
```